# find text in files and copy to a csv

Tags: grep, pcregrep

I need to extract the text in a bunch of html files (about 500K of them)
The text to be copied looks like `<div class='cls '>text to be copied including some<span>and <p></p></span>and more text</div>`

which I resolved to `(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)`

I've read other questions about how to do this with grep and I thought the command would be

```
grep -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html > output.txt
```

And it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

also tried `pcregrep -r -regexp="/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" --file-list=fl.txt > output.txt` - it does nothing
and `pcregrep -r -regexp="/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" > output.txt` - nothing

EDIT 1: 
Tried the suggestion below in the following formats:

```
grep -f -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'desc\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html >> touch output.txt
grep: -r: No such file or directory
grep -f -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'desc\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html >> output.txt
grep: -r: No such file or directory
grep -f -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'desc\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html >> output.txt
grep: -r: No such file or directory

 grep -f "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'desc\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" file111.html >> touch output.txt
grep: /(?:\<div\sclass\=\'desc\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/: No such file or directory
```

and a few other permutations, still nothing

Comment: What output do you want from the command? (1) `text to be copied including some<span>and <p></p></span>and more text`, (2) `<div class='cls '>text to be copied including some<span>and <p></p></span>and more text</div>` (i.e., including the `<div …>` and the `</div>`), or (3) the entire line containing the above?  I interpreted the question to mean that you wanted #1, and so that's what my answer gives you, but you accepted an answer that gives you #3. … … … P.S. Can you have multiple `<div …>` … `</div>` pairs on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you added all those bells ad whistles. This simple regex worked for me:

```
grep "<div\sclass='cls\s'>.*<\/div>" file
<div class='cls '>text to be copied including some<span>and <p></p></span>and more text</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining, please? The simplified regex I understand, but how exactly do I copy what's inside the files into another file?

Comment: By redirecting stdout to some file, like you did already. `-f` needs a "pattern file"; that may cause your new edited-in error.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. One more thing if you don't mind. The issue as far as I see it is that I was adding the -r  (my first try was this: grep -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html > output.txt ). You dropped the -r and it works. Why would it break on -r?

Comment: It doesn't. `man grep`:      -r, --recursive
              Read  all  files  under  each directory, recursively,

Answer (score 2):

You have six problems:

1. You are including `/` at the beginning and end of your regex. 
   You type `/regex/` in `sed`, `vi`,
   and other programs to do a search, but you don't need it for `grep`. 
   And, in fact, `grep` will just include literal `/` characters in the pattern.
2. To use PCREs in (plain) `grep`, you must use `-P`.
3. There's no such thing as `-regexp`; it has to be `--regexp`. 
   Or leave off the `—regexp=` and just give the regular expression
   as an unadorned argument, as you do in `grep`.

Once I fixed the above errors, both commands (`grep -P` and `pcregrep`)
sort-of worked — but they printed the entire line containing the pattern,
including any text before the `<div …>` or after the `</div>`.

4. To print just the text that matched the pattern, you must specify `-o`.

Even after I fixed that, I got the `<div …>` in the output
(but not the text before the `<div …>`,
or the `</div>` or anything after it). 
So,

5. There's something wrong with your look-behind group —
   it's being included in the match.

   Unfortunately, I don't know enough about PCREs to know
   exactly what the problem is or how to fix it. 
   Fortunately, I know enough about `pcregrep` to know a work-around. 
   If you have multiple capture groups in your regex,
   `pcregrep` lets you pick which one(s) you want written to the output. 
   So, we can get it to work in `pcregrep`
   by turning the look-behind into a capture group,
   and then ignoring it:

   ```
   pcregrep -o2 -r "(\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)"
   ```

   But even that's more complicated than it needs to be. 
   The first (`<div …>`) group doesn't need to be a capture group;
   i.e., it doesn't have to be a group at all. 
   Likewise, the last group (the `</div>` look-ahead group)
   doesn't have to be a group at all. 
   The only thing that needs to be a group is the part you want to capture —
   the part between the `<div …>` and the `</div>`:

   ```
   pcregrep -o1 -r "\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>(.*)\<\/div\>"
   ```

   Note that I changed `-o2` to `-o1` because now there is only one group.

   BTW, as [RudiC discovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483681/23408#483689) (but did not mention),
   almost none of those backslashes are necessary. 
   AFAICT, the only ones you need are the ones in the `\s` strings;
   so we can simplify the above to:

   ```
   pcregrep -o1 -r "<div\sclass='cls\s'>(.*)</div>"
   ```

   Now that we've eliminated all the PCRE-ish parts of the regex
   (look-ahead and look-behind),
   you might think we can use this regex with plain `grep`. 
   Unfortunately, we can't; the above command
   depends on the `-oN` option,
   which `grep` doesn't have.

   However, we can use it with `sed`!

   ```
   sed -n -r "s|.*<div\sclass='cls\s'>(.*)</div>.*|\1|p"
   ```

   Like the `pcregrep` command, this searches for the entire regex
   (including stuff before the `<div …>` or after the `</div>`,
   because I added `.*` at the beginning and end)
   and replaces it with the #1 capture group (the only one). 
   The `p` at the end causes it to print lines that match;
   the `-n` option causes it not to print lines that don't match.

   The above uses `|` as a regex delimiter because the regex contains `/`. 
   If you want to use `/` as your delimiter,
   then you have to escape the textual `/` (in `</div>`):

   ```
   sed -n -r "s/.*<div\sclass='cls\s'>(.*)<\/div>.*/\1/p"
   ```

   Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't have a recursive search capability. 
   The `-r` option to `sed` is like the `-E` option to `grep`;
   it specifies the use of extended regular expressions (EREs). 
   Without it, we would need to use `\(` and `\)` for the capture group:

   ```
   sed -n    "s/.*<div\sclass='cls\s'>\(.*\)<\/div>.*/\1/p"
   ```

   Of course you can do a recursive search by running `sed` through `find`.

   P.S. If you have multiple `<div …>` … `</div>` pairs on one line,
   these `sed` commands will print only the first one.
6. You're doing the recursive (directory tree) search wrong.

   ```
   grep -r regex *.html
   ```

   (and `pcregrep` the same) looks in every `.html` file,
   and then looks at *every* file in and under any
   ***directory whose name ends with* `.html`**. 
   So, in the (unlikely?) event
   that you have a subdirectory called `foo.html`,
   then the above command would search *every* file in that directory
   (even if it's called `Makefile` or `README.txt`). 
   If (as I assume is more likely) you have subdirectories
   with names like `page42` and `index`, they would not be searched.

   What you want to do is:

   ```
   grep -r --include='*.html' regex .
   ```

   which does a recursive search of all directories
   starting from **`.`** (the current directory),
   looking only at files whose names match `*.html`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -r "/(?:\<div\sclass\=\'cls\s\'\>)(.*)(?=\<\/div\>)/" *.html > output.txt
```

Is working recursively but not interpreting regex. Try using fgrep instead or grep -f -r. 
Also you may want to `touch output.txt` and use >> instead of >.

Comment: if I add anything else (like grep -r -f or grep -f -r or >> or any combination thereof) I get a "No such file or directory" error

Comment: Even with output.txt existing in cwd?

Comment: yes, output.txt exists and still has 0 bytes

Comment: Ok, so the issue must be with the grep statement. If you don't redirect the output, does anything come out?

Comment: I used fgrep "<div\sclass='cls\s'>.*<\/div>" f1.html
and  fgrep "<div\sclass='cls\s'>.*<\/div>" f1.html > output.txt
and nothing happens.

Comment: The other answer worked. Thank you for helping

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out